# How to create pair from two stack, in a clever way

Tags: java

I have a two stack; `Stack<String> file` and `Stack<String[]>author`. They have one-to-one relationship, i.e

```
file            author

file1        author3, author2    // file1 is written by author3 and author2
file2        author1, author2    // file2 is written by author1 and author2
```

I have tried to create new data structure, ( I though Map is best ) to contain all information in pair. For example;

```
new data structure

author1, file2
author2, file1, file2
author3, file1
```

To create this pair, I have used `HashMap<String, Set<String> allInfo`, and implemented the concatanation as;

```
int len = author.size();

   for(int i = 0 ; i <len ; i ++ ){
      String []temp = author.pop(); 
      int len2 = temp.length();

      for(int j = 0 ; j <len2 ; j ++ ){
          if(allInfo.contains(temp[j]) == false){
                Set<String> list = new HashSet<String>();
                allInfo.put(temp[j], list);
          }

          Set<String> temp2 = allInfo.get(temp[j]);
          temp2.add(file.pop());
      }
   }
```

However, it seems this implementation is so ugly. How can I create this pair more cleverly? ( Relying on built-in method of Java is preferred. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is only a little better. There are (non-JDK) libraries around that provide a data structure called multimap, which is more convenient. But you are stuck with the two stacks, and the inverse ordering of associations, so you'll need a little coding effort.

```
while( ! author.empty() ){
  String f = file.pop();   // Note that in your code this is in the wrong place
  for( String aut: author.pop() ){
    Set<String> files = allInfo.get( aut );
    if( files == null ){
      files = new HashSet<>();
      allInfo.put( aut, files );
    }
    files.add( f );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having a custom type for your problem?

```
public class AuthorPublication{

private String authorName;

private Set<String> files;

//setters and getters

}
```

Comment: Please explain how this improves matters? It does not avoid the use of a `Map<String,AuthorPublication>`. Basically, the `Map.Entry<String,Set<String>>` is what you propose, so what?